# Logrotate Tomcat log file

Tags: logrotate, tomcat

I am writing Tomcat log with this setting:

- Log configured using an `AccessLogValve` in `server.xml`

  ```
  Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs/access"
  prefix="access" suffix=".log" pattern="common" rotatable="false"
  ```
- Use `logrotate` to rotate the log file daily and remove old log files.

  ```
  /app/logs/access/access.log {
      daily
      dateext
      missingok
      rotate 14
      maxage 14
      compress
      delaycompress
      dateyesterday }
  ```

The strange thing is that every day the log file is changed to a new name by `logrotate`, for example `access.log-20171222`, and a new log file `access.log` is created. However, Tomcat still writes log to the renamed file.

My solution now is adding the option `copytruncate` to the configuration file of `logrotate`. However, with this option, there is a chance of losing some log at the time of truncating.

Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes) documentation you should keep the rotatable option as true (default) so that it does not write always to the same file.
Also you can format the filename string to a fixed value, so that you do not get dates on them. Just be sure to run logrotate before the internal rotation so that the new log does not risk overwriting the last (as it gets renamed).

Comment: It seems to be a good idea. I will try and tell you the result :)

Comment: It does not work because in the documentation of Tomcat, it say
`fileDateFormat 
Allows a customized timestamp in the access log file name. The file is rotated whenever the formatted timestamp changes. The default value is .yyyy-MM-dd. If you wish to rotate every hour, then set this value to .yyyy-MM-dd.HH. The date format will always be localized using the locale en_US.`

So the file name always has date in it

Comment: Indeed... Perhaps you can get something better customizable with login or a renaming script with the logrotate routine...

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean login, meant log4j